# Probability of draw in the football match

Tags: probability

Some football team shoot $n$ goal with probability $p^n(1-p)$. Independently, second team shoot $m$ goals with probability $q^m(1-q)$. How is probability that will draw with goals?

I think that propability of draw with goals is equal:

$p(1-p)q(1-q) + p^2(1-p)q^2(1-q) + p^3(1-p)q^3(1-q) + ... = \frac{pq(1-p)(1-q)}{1-pq}$

Is it good?

Comment: Is there  the possibility that both teams had zero goals?

Comment: No. So both teams have one goals (draw 1:1) or two goals (draw 2:2) or three goals (draw 3:3) and so on.

Comment: In that case, what you have is correct.

Comment: Ok thank you. Could you tell me, if we admit draw without goals (i.e. we admit draw 0:0) then propability of draw with goals is equal $(1-p)(1-q) + p(1-p)q(1-q) + p^2(1-p)q^2(1-q) + p^3(1-p)q^3(1-q) + ... $

Comment: Yes, that's correct.